# Beta vs. Permanent

Tags: discussion, beta

How long does a site, like Law beta, stay in the beta stage before becoming a permanent site? Is it a timeframe benchmark or a user benchmark?

If this information is in a specific area, can you please add a link.

Answer (score 4):

Good question!  This was actually [addressed by Stack Exchange a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/241697).

If you want to get a sense of how the site is doing you can always check in on its [Area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law).  (However, as [one commentator noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840143_257614), "Even the SE team has repeatedly emphasized that the current A51 stats do not matter as to whether a site will be graduated, as there are far more important (and subjective) goals, such as sense of community, self-moderation, user retention, etc....")

For such a young beta Law is (currently) doing extraordinarily well.

Comment: tl;dr: >10 questions per day, and around a year or so of existence, maybe less. Also one of the factors that have previously prevented graduation for at least one other site is a high number of unanswered questions. (But may or may not be a factor for us.)

Comment: Also, as long as we continue to produce useful content (regardless of question volume), and the moderators keep things tidy, we don't need to be worried about the site being closed.